# Как с помощью python вставить страничку из одного PDF в другой

Tags: python, pdf

Есть код, который в конец файла test.pdf вставляет страничку из файла last.pdf

```
import fitz

original_pdf_path = "test.pdf"
extra_page_path = "last.pdf"
output_file_path = "example-extended.pdf"

original_pdf = fitz.open(original_pdf_path)
extra_page = fitz.open(extra_page_path)

original_pdf.insert_pdf(extra_page, to_page=0)
original_pdf.save(output_file_path)
```

Все прекрасно работает, но теперь мне нужно из файла `five.pdf` взять страничку и вставить ее пятой по номеру в файл test.pdf

`original_pdf.insert_page(second_page_copy, 1)` не помогло

`original_pdf.insert_pdf(five_page_path, to_page=0, start_at=1)`
выдает ошибку

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "/Users/iriska/Projects/test/stati/pdf.py", line 14, in <module>  
>     original_pdf.insert_pdf(extra_page_path, to_page=0, start_at=1)  
>   File "/Users/iriska/Projects/test/stati/venv/lib/python3.11/site- 
>  packages/fitz/fitz.py", line 4589, in insert_pdf  
>     if self._graft_id == docsrc._graft_id:  
>                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_graft_id'
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, которую именно страницу вы хотели взять из файла `five.pdf`, потому пусть ее номер в переменной `n` (для первой примените `n=0`, для второй `n=1`, и т.д.).

Сделайте так:

```
n = 1            # вторая страница (например) из файла `five.pdf`

five_page_doc = fitz.open(five_page_path)
original_pdf.insert_pdf(five_page_doc, from_page=n, to_page=n, start_at=4)
```

---

*Объяснение:*

1. Ваша первая попытка:

   > ```
   > original_pdf.insert_page(second_page_copy, 1) не помогло
   > ```

   Метод `.insert_page()` не для того, что вы хотите (он вставит новую страницу с текстом, который вы задаете как параметр).
2. Ваша вторая попытка — правильный метод, неправильные параметры:

   > ```
   > original_pdf.insert_pdf(five_page_path, to_page=0, start_at=1) выдает ошибку
   > ```

   Я предполагаю, что ваш первый аргумент `five_page_path` не документ, а только **путь к нему** (т.е. строка). Надо сначала документ *открыть*

   ```
   five_page_doc =  fitz.open(five_page_path)
   ```

   а только зятем применить **его** как первый аргумент метода `.insert_pdf()`:

   ```
   original_pdf.insert_pdf(five_page_doc, from_page=n, to_page=n, start_at=4)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         открытый документ
   ```

   (Я исправил значение параметра `start_at` т.к. вы хотели вставить ее *пятой по номеру.*)

Comment: Большое спасибо) Действительно, уже залез в документацию и все заработало. Видимо, нужно переставать писать в 3 часа ночи, чтобы не задавать глупых вопросов

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу читать на вашем языке, но из сообщения об ошибке я могу сказать, что этот метод `.insert_pdf(src, ...)` требует, чтобы "src" был ***PDF-документом***, а не именем файла!

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).